# Cannot Run MediaCreationTool1909

Tags: windows

I'm trying to do a clean install of Windows 10 Pro; I currently have Windows 7 Pro.

For several days I've been trying to run the MediaCreationTool1909.

I'm repeatedly getting this error:

**There was a problem running this tool**
We're not sure what happened, but we're unable to run this tool on your PC. If you continue experiencing problems,reference the error code when contacting customer support. Error code: 0x80070424 - 0x90018

It goes to these screens:

*Getting a few things ready
Applicable notices and license terms*

After accepting it goes back to

*Getting a few things ready screen*
*What do you want to do?*

After selecting

*Create installation media (USB flash drive, DVD, or ISO file) for another PC*

and clicking "Next" it goes to

*Select language, architecture, and edition*

I select English (United States), Windows 10, and 64-bit

and leaving "Use the recommended options for this PC" checked (I've tried both: same result) and clicking "Next" it goes to the screen to pick USB or ISO (I've tried both: same result).

It then asks me to select the drive.

When I select the USB drive where the MediaCreationTool1909 is I immediately get the same message.

I've tried selecting other drives on my system.

Same result.

I spent hours Googling this and trying all sorts of fixes, mostly involving ensuring that several specific services were set to automatic (they were).

I tried two different blank 30 GB NFST-formatted thumb drives that I know work, tried several different onboard USB ports, but no luck.

I redownloaded a new file several times, from both Firefox and Chrome.

I disabled my antivirus (ESET NOD32) and Malwarebytes Premium.

I looked at other options to create a bootable USB from an ISO file, but all roads seem to lead to the same process: going through the media creation tool (MediaCreationTool1909).

Is there a way to directly download an ISO, save to USB and install from there?

**UPDATE: Decided to try this on my wife's desktop and IT WORKED!
The total size of the download is about 4 GB: I hope that's correct.**

Comment: Maybe it cannot out out to the internet, check firewall settings or disable it and see if it works now, then re enable when done.

Comment: How much free space do you have on your system drive?

Comment: You might be able to download an ISO image by changing your browser UserAgent to pretend you are running Linux or another system: https://www.howtogeek.com/427223/how-to-download-a-windows-10-iso-without-the-media-creation-tool/

Comment: I'll check the firewall; nothing is weird with the settings.. My system drive has 215 GB free.

Comment: I'll also look at that ISO thread. Thank you.

Comment: You get this error at what point exactly in the process of running the tool?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment.  I assume you are getting this [error](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/89ba4fcf-9716-4904-a9cc-e995b969ffaf) almost immediately.

Comment: Added details. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest skipping using the Media Creation Tool and instead use download the current Windows 10 version 1909 ISO and use Rufus instead.  There are far to many reason for this particular error to diagnose your issue

Comment: I updated my question. I got it to work on another machine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as non-reproducible because the author got it to work on another machine.